# Comparing nested array to dictionary values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[[ 36 119]
 [ 36 148]
 [ 36 179]
 [ 67 209]
 [ 69  84]
 [ 96 240]]
```

and a dictionary like this:

```
{84: [36, 119], 85: [36, 148], 86: [36, 160]}
```

I would like to check if any of the values of the array are present in the dictionary, then return the numbers. So for the example above it should return 84, 85. I tried to compare using:

```
pairs = zip(array, dict)
print(any(x != y for x, y in pairs))
```

Although I get an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: You're using NumPy, right? It would help if you added the [tag:numpy] tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.isin` and `np.ndarray.all`:

```
>>> pairs = {84: [36, 119], 85: [36, 148], 86: [36, 160]}
>>> array 
array([[ 36, 119],
       [ 36, 148],
       [ 36, 179],
       [ 67, 209],
       [ 69,  84],
       [ 96, 240]])

>>> [k for k, v in pairs.items() if np.isin(v, array).all()]
[84, 85]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```python
>>> my_dict = {84: [36, 119], 85: [36, 148], 86: [36, 160]}
>>> x = np.array([[ 36, 119], [ 36, 148], [ 36, 179], [ 67, 209], [ 69 ,84],[96,240]])
>>> [keys for (keys, value) in my_dict.items() if (x == value).all(axis=1).any()]
[84, 85]
```